# Is it possible to add the same ImageView multiple times to a screen?

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I am using a RelativeLayout for my whole screen. The images on the screen appear and disappear almost randomly, and it often happens that the same image is displayed multiple times. However, when this happens, I get an error saying: "Child already has a parent....".

Do you guys know any way around this? I thought I could probably dynamically change the reference ID for each ImageView that is called onto the screen, but as I will have probably like 50+ imageviews on the screen, dynamically changing positions, disappearing and coming back, wouldn't that slow down the program a lot?

Comment: create new instances of imageview everytime. That should be ok. Though dvm does garbage collect as and when required, it might help to set object reference to null after every add

Answer (score 4):

Each `View` must have on `Parent` that when added to it ,it can't be added to another `Parent` .

if you want you can cache the `bitmap` some where and apply it to different `ImageViews`. so both `imageviews` will have the same `bitmap` . but you cant have the same `ImageView` in different Parents .

Comment: I'm sorry, but you didn't get my question right. I want to add one ImageView multiple times to the SAME parent. Thank you.